# How to handle freezing libraries in production with Django?

Tags: python, django, pipenv

I have a Django application where I use `pipenv` to manage packages. Now I want to freeze all the libraries to their current versions to avoid problems in the production. Is it enough just to lock the versions in the `Pipfile`, or should I handle the dependency packages as well? These are my packages from the `Pipfile`:

```
[packages]
Django = "*"
djangorestframework-simplejwt = "*"
django-rest-framework = "*"
django-cors-headers = "*"
pytest-django = "*"
psycopg2-binary = "*"
```

If I run the command `pipenv run pip freeze > requirements.txt` I get a long list of packages and versions because it contains also the packages that my `Pipfile` packages are dependent of. So should I lock all those packages also, or is it enough to lock the packages in the `Pipfile` to prevent any unwanted changes happening?

Comment: If you really want to freeze the version, add them instead of `*` each package. You could consider keeping the main version but allow minor updates: `package = "2.*"`

Comment: @Christophe Maybe I wasn't clear. I was asking should I freeze just the packages in my Pipfile, or should I also freeze all the packages that are dependencies for my packages?

Comment: Just run `pipenv lock` to generate `pipfile.lock`; `pipenv` will then use that for installation. I recommend [pip-tools](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools) if you want to deploy into a pipenv-less environment.

Comment: if there is any dependency(of package) which you manually had to `pip install` then that should also be in your requirement rest you can leave.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at this
https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools